# angular.js:Error: $injector:modulerr when ngsanitize used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code for my app.js

I have include all the required files for angular. It is showing an error, but only when I include the `ngSanitize` module.

```
 <script src="resources/scripts/ext/angular-1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/scripts/ext/angular-1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/scripts/ext/angular-1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/scripts/ext/angular-1.2.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

App.js

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('zinapp-db-app', [ 'ngRoute','ngResource','ngSanitize'])
```

Here is error

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=zinapp-db-app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngSanitize%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngSanitize%250At%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A443%250AYc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%252Fb%255Be%255D%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A254%250AYc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A142%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A1%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A278%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A32%253A445%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A1%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A278%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A32%253A445%250Aac%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A32%250A%2524b%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A17%253A429%250A%2524b%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A133%250AWc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A17%253A212%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fangular-1.2.16%252Fangular.min.js%253A209%253A360%250AjQuery.Callbacks%252Ffire%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.9.1.js%253A1037%253A1%250AjQuery.Callbacks%252Fself.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.9.1.js%253A1148%253A7%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.9.1.js%253A433%253A3%250Acompleted%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252FZinappViewBeta%252Fresources%252Fscripts%252Fext%252Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.9.1.js%253A103%253A4%250A%0At%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A443%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A221%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A278%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A445%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A1%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A278%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A445%0Aac%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A32%0A%24b%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A429%0A%24b%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A133%0AWc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A212%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fangular-1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A209%3A360%0AjQuery.Callbacks%2Ffire%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.9.1.js%3A1037%3A1%0AjQuery.Callbacks%2Fself.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.9.1.js%3A1148%3A7%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.9.1.js%3A433%3A3%0Acompleted%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FZinappViewBeta%2Fresources%2Fscripts%2Fext%2Fjquery-ui-1.10.3.custom%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.9.1.js%3A103%3A4%0A


...p"+(c-1)+"="+encodeURIComponent("function"==typeof arguments[c]?arguments[c].toS..
```

Comment: If you include `angular-sanitize.js` rather than `angular-sanitize.min.js`, it should give you a more verbose error message that might help you more in your debugging.

Comment: `'use strict';` is well known in angular to provoke this kind of errors, I would try to remove it and see. Otoh, don't use .min in development, ever.